# Set commit message error using Gerrit-python-api package

Tags: python, gerrit

Link to the documentation of package python-gerrit-api:

https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gerrit.changes.html?highlight=get_edit#gerrit.changes.change.GerritChange.set_commit_message

Code:

input_ = {
"message": "New Commit message \n\nChange-Id: xxxxxxxxx\n"
}

change = gerrit.changes.get('xxxxxxxxx')

result = change.set_commit_message(input_)

Error:

I get "gerrit.utils.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Client Error: Not Found" as error when I try to set a commit message using the above package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue as you asked in your other question. If you have a child parent project it will try to access the project as parent/child instead of parent%2Fchild. This will result in error 404

For a fix see the pull request. See: https://github.com/shijl0925/python-gerrit-api/pull/5

An example of a parent and child relation is the  code-owners plugin at gerrit. The plugin repository does not contain any code, it is more like a folder that contains sub repositories and these child repositories normally will inherit the access rights from the parent.

If you look at the below url you can see that the url uses %2F and not the forward slash. That is what is not working in the gerrit-python-api

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/q/project:plugins%252Fcode-owners+status:open

This example works for me with the above pull request

```
input_ = {"message" : "New commit message\n\nChange-Id: I46554af336396ecb57d0c270c114a686439b5a66\n"}
c1 = gerrit.changes.get("12321")
print (c1)
c1.set_commit_message(input_)
```

Comment: endpoint = "/changes/%s/message" % quote(self.id).
I tried changing the endpoint value in set_commit_message function of gerrit python api library.Still I get the error

Comment: what is the url that you are using? I added some logging to gerrit/__init__.py to show the end point url and return values.

Comment: URL:https://gerrit.xxx.xx.com/a/changes/xxxxx/message

Comment: url should be server/a/changes/Folder%2Fprojectname~branch~changeID/message

Comment: I get a 404 client error in the terminal along with this link:https://gerrit.xx.xxx.com/a/changes/main~service~changeID/message when I run the above code.I dont see a parent and child project relationship.
But GET Request on the same link does return the answer.I got the link from error itself and I got response via POSTMAN.

Comment: I dont see any parent child relationship in the project.Could u please elaborate on that more ?

Comment: I made the changes as per the pull request u created but I still get the error.
raise NotFoundError(http_error_msg)
gerrit.utils.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://gerrit.xxx.xxx.com/a/changes/xxx/message